# Проблема с плагином easyzoom.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Использую плагин  easyzoom.js для изображений, но требуется он только для ПК, а для моб. устройст он работать не должен. Поэтому испльзую его с enquire.js.

```
  var $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom();
  enquire.register("screen and (max-width:1100px)", {
    match: function() {
      var api = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--adjacent').data('easyZoom');
      api.teardown();
    },
    unmatch: function() {
      var api = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--adjacent').data('easyZoom');
      api._init();
    },
  });
```

Проблема в том, что все вроде бы работает но в консоли постоянно ошибка.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'teardown' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'teardown' of undefined
    at Object.match (http://dm/design/kids/js/main.js:12:11)
    at e.on (http://dm/design/kids/js/enquire.js:7:992)
    at f.addHandler (http://dm/design/kids/js/enquire.js:7:1297)
    at http://dm/design/kids/js/enquire.js:7:1894
    at b (http://dm/design/kids/js/enquire.js:7:282)
    at g.register (http://dm/design/kids/js/enquire.js:7:1853)
    at HTMLDocument. (http://dm/design/kids/js/main.js:8:11)
    at j (http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) undefined
```

```
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'teardown' of undefined
    at Object.match (main.js:12)
    at e.on (enquire.js:7)
    at f.addHandler (enquire.js:7)
    at enquire.js:7
    at b (enquire.js:7)
    at g.register (enquire.js:7)
    at HTMLDocument. (main.js:8)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
```

Как ее исправить?

Comment: Вам же написано, что у вас не находит функцию teardown(), я 100% уверен и не находит и само api.

Comment: @DimenSi, я вижу, что не находит. Но почему и как это исправть?
И при этом все работает. Js практически не знаю, но в файле плагина есть вот эта часть кода
b.prototype.teardown = function() {
        this.hide(), this.$target.off(".easyzoom").removeClass("is-loading is-ready is-error"), this.detachNotice && clearTimeout(this.detachNotice), delete this.$link, delete this.$zoom, delete this.$image, delete this.$notice, delete this.$flyout, delete this.isOpen, delete this.isReady
    }

Comment: Я думаю, вам надо лезть не в исходники плагина, а в свой код. Вы уверены, что фильтр находит то, что нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете фильтр не на том. Вы пытаетесь фильтровать дом элементы, а я не уверен, что плагин их вам возвращает.
Просто вместо

```
$easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--adjacent').data('easyZoom');
```

Ищите

```
$('.easyzoom--adjacent').data('easyZoom');
```

Comment: Как оказалось проблема не решилась, та же ошибка.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53085/easyzoom-js

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.easyzoom--adjacent').data('easyZoom');
```

Comment: Дубль ответа @DimenSi.